# Trove Library Queue implementation

Tags: java, queue, implementation, trove4j

I am using trove 3.0.3 library in java project.
All classes in gnu.trove.queue (TByteQueue, TDoubleQueue ...) are all interfaces.
Where I can find implementation of Queue classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Queues are not yet implemented in Trove.

Comment: is there a plan to do so?

Comment: @AlexAverbuch Unlikely. Use GS collections

Comment: Thanks @leventov. Are you a/the Trove developer?

Comment: @AlexAverbuch no, but there is no considerable activity in the Trove repo for years.

Comment: to not hijack this question I've created a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706930/looking-for-sorted-heap-concurrent-queue-in-gs-collections-library it would be great if you could assist!

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate simple Queue of double using TDoubleLinkedList. It can insert to tail and to head in O(1) time.