# looking for Sorted Heap & Concurrent Queue in gs-collections library

Tags: java, collections, queue, heap, gs-collections

Three questions:

1. I was told the `gs-collections` library contains queue implementations but I can't find them in http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/javadoc/5.1.0/. do they exist? if so, which classes should I look at?
2. Likewise for a sorted heap class
3. (Not so much of a question) Does anyone have any experience with the `gs-collections` library? It's totally new to me, so if you have any experience and advice regarding which tasks it's particular good at please share

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about GS collections and your cases, but you also might be interested in these libraries:

- https://github.com/JCTools/JCTools for very efficient concurrent queues
- http://fastutil.di.unimi.it for priority queues

Comment: I tried a JCTools MPSC Bounded queue (that fits best with current design), and it was more than 2x faster than LinkedBlockingQueue, for my use case. Thanks!
I think I'll try Disruptor next, for comparison.

Answer (score 5):

1. No, GS Collections doesn't have Queue implementations yet. You could raise a request in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-collections/issues).
2. No, GS Collections doesn't have a sorted heap yet. As a first step toward supporting one, GS Collections could have a QueueAdapter which could wrap a java.util.PriorityQueue but add additional API.
3. I am a developer on GS Collections. We're watching the gs-collections tag and can help. This is a broad question so I'll write a short answer here and you can write a new top level question if you'd like to go into it more.

GS Collections is particularly good when:

- You need a container that isn't provided by the JCF or other collections libraries, like Multimaps, Bags, BiMaps, primitive collections, or immutable collections.
- You run the JVM with a lot of memory / you have GC problems / you need memory-efficient containers. For example, UnifiedMap uses half the memory of HashMap and UnifiedSet uses a quarter of the memory of HashSet. Multimaps, Bags, and BiMaps are built on top of these more efficient structures.
- You want a rich API on your collections. Most collections implement [RichIterable](http://www.goldmansachs.com/gs-collections/javadoc/5.1.0/com/gs/collections/api/RichIterable.html) which provides many iteration pattern methods.